# Add alert when transfer in BigQuery results in "succeeded 0 jobs"

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I have a schedule transfer running daily on BigQuery and mostly without any issues. The transfer reads a .csv file from an AWS S3 bucket and appends the information to a BigQuery table.

Recently there has been an issue where the transfer resulted in neither succeeded nor failed jobs.

[transfer logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQVkl.png)

The outcome was that no entries were imported but also no alert was triggered; I had to hear from the reports' users that something had gone wrong.

Question: is there a way to add an alert on BigQuery Transfers for when `successful jobs = 0`?

Comment: Sorry to piggy back on this, but what was your issue in no rows being added? I'm getting "Summary: succeeded 0 jobs, failed 0 jobs." on a lot of my jobs and can't figure out the issue. Post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138865/bigquery-data-transfer-from-s3-intermittent-success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery does have monitoring, it has some known issues as well, this will help [BigQuery Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring)

Monitoring->Dashboard->Add Chart->Use Resource type Global and Metric type as "Uploaded rows".